# How to not trigger childEventListener for firebase realtime database on a device when setting a value on same device?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently having some issues with firebase realtime database.

When I e.g. delete an entry from the realtime database like so `myRef.child(ID).setValue(null)` the childEventListener

```
val firebaseItemsListener = object : ChildEventListener {
        override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            Log.i("onChildAdded",dataSnapshot.toString())
        }
        override fun onChildChanged(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            Log.i("onChildChanged",dataSnapshot.toString())
        }
        override fun onChildRemoved(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            Log.i("onChildRemoved",dataSnapshot.toString())
        }
        override fun onChildMoved(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            Log.i("onChildMoved",dataSnapshot.toString())
        }
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.i("onCancelled",databaseError.toString())
        }
    }
    myRef.addChildEventListener(firebaseItemsListener)
```

will be notified, more specificly the onChildRemoved part in this case.
Now when I swipe away and delete an entry from a recyclerview on my phone I know that that entry is already deleted and I don't want my phone specifically to be notified because my phone doesn't need that information but firebase will trigger the onChildRemoved part anyway and inform my device about that change, which I don't want to happen.
My question now is if there is an intended way to do this by firebase themselfs or some custom way I have to come up with?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When using `ChildEventListener`,  you can't control if this `onChildRemoved()` will trigger or not.

What you can do is ignore the callback and do nothing in the method.

```
    override fun onChildRemoved(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

     //do nothing here, when notified of a deleted child

    }
```

Comment: This is pretty much it indeed. When the child node is removed from Firebase , it will call `onChildRemoved` - there's no way to prevent that. So you'll either have to ignore these events, or detect otherwise when `onChildRemoved` is for a node that was removed locally. In some of our early sample apps we kept a list of such local changes that were pending DB writes: so you'd add the node/key to that list when the swipe happens, and then check that list in `onChildRemoved`, and remove the key/node from the list when the database has also processed that swipe/remove.